# if i click anything from another pc on my local website it listen to localhost

Tags: php, database

[it listen to localhost but i access it from ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nzO1.png)

[Before i click login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmRuf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to provide snippet which redirects to login?
What I am guessing is the base url for the login may have been statically set to "localhost".